# Как на php вырезать из контента слайдер?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, slider, шорткод

Приветствую. Есть у меня сайт на wordpress и есть на странице слайдер, который выводится с помощью шорткода `[rev_slider]`. Краткое описание поста получаю таким способом `$post_content = mad_post_content_truncate(get_the_content(), 100, " ", "...");`, где на выходе имею `html`

```
<div class="entry-body ">
<div id="rev_slider_1_1_wrapper" class="rev_slider_wrapper fullwidthbanner-container">
<!-- START REVOLUTION SLIDER 4.6.93 fullwidth mode -->
<div id="rev_slider_1_1" class="rev_slider fullwidthabanner">...</div>
</div>
<!-- END REVOLUTION SLIDER -->
Булочки в форме полумесяцев (нем. Kipferl) выпекались...
</div>
```

Вопрос: как вырезать  из контента весь слайдер с содержимым (может располагаться в любом произвольном месте контента) и сохранить в какой-нить переменной, чтобы иметь возможность с ним работать?

Пробую решить через `strpos`, сам слайдер нахожу, но пока не знаю что делать дальше

```
$pos = strpos($post_content, 'slider'); if($pos) {..}
```

Comment: Зачем вырезать? Если вы его формируете в php коде, то формируйте в нужном месте сразу.

Comment: @Visman в смысле? я его получаю внутри контента, а вырезать нужно, чтобы расположить в определенном месте обособленно от текста, поэтому вопрос остается

Comment: @Visman почему сразу закрыть? в описание добавил, что я делал. я же не прошу полностью решить - хотя бы подсказать, что делать

Comment: @Вася, раз у вас слайдер выводится с помощью шорткода, то этот шорткод можно убрать из разметки. (Или я не прав?) А дальше использовать кусок кода, который генерирует слайдер, что бы получить разметку для слайдера. И не нужно ничего вырезать.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, нет. У меня на странице блога слайдер выводится так, как его разместят в контенте, а на странице категорий, которая состоит из краткого описания страниц блога - он должен выводится в определенном месте отдельно от текста - вот я и спрашиваю как его извлечь?
Что-то упорно никто не пробует ответить на вопрос, а пробует все искать обходные варианты. У меня же вроде конкретный насущный вопрос...

Answer (score 1):

Если PHP 5.4 и Libxml 2.6 то можно так

```
<?php

$post_content = '<div class="entry-body ">
<div id="rev_slider_1_1_wrapper" class="rev_slider_wrapper fullwidthbanner-container">
<!-- START REVOLUTION SLIDER 4.6.93 fullwidth mode -->
<div id="rev_slider_1_1" class="rev_slider fullwidthabanner">...</div>
</div>
<!-- END REVOLUTION SLIDER -->
Булочки в форме полумесяцев (нем. Kipferl) выпекались...
</div>';

// создаем DOM дерево
$dom = new DOMDocument;
// этот кусок нужно добавлять для правильной работы с кодировкой
$xmlEncodding = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
// парсим строку с HTML
$dom->loadHTML($xmlEncodding . $post_content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
if (!$dom) {
    // Ошибка при разборе документа
}
// ищем слайдер по аттрибуту – id
$slider = $dom->getElementById('rev_slider_1_1_wrapper');
// удаляем слайдер и получаем его в ответе
$oldSlider = $slider->parentNode->removeChild($slider);
// созраняем контент без слайдера в строку
$content = str_replace($xmlEncodding, '', $dom->saveHTML());
// сохраняем слайдер в строку
$sliderContent = $dom->saveHTML($oldSlider);
// удаляем временные переменные
unset($slider);
unset($dom);
unset($oldSlider);
// используем переменные где нужно
echo $content;
echo $sliderContent;

?>
```

Comment: отличная попытка, но еще пока не удается вырезать сам слайдер. `dom` получаю нормально - вот что пишет `var_dump($dom)` `object(DOMDocument)#8431 (34) {.. ["textContent"]=> string(114) " <div id="rev_slider_1_1_wrapper"></div>Булочки в форме полумесяцев (нем. Kipferl) выпекались...}`
как я понимаю - нужно здесь `$dom->getElementById()` еще обратиться сразу к `textContent`

Comment: т.е. вот так `var_dump($dom->textContent);` конечно я слайдер получаю, но вот это `$slider3 = $dom->textContent->getElementsByClassName('rev_slider');` сразу выбивает ошибку..

Comment: Потому что $dom->textContent – это текст элемента без тегов. Код рабочий, см. документацию

Comment: обновил ответ. Скопируй в php файл и выполни.

Comment: скопипастил, и тем не менее где-то у меня ошибка после этого фрагмента..(( `$slider = $dom->getElementById('rev_slider_1_1_wrapper');` на `$slider` var_dump пишет Null

Comment: Какая ошибка? Версия php? Кодировка файла?

Comment: php 5.4.4 кодировка utf-8

Comment: попробуй добавить `$doм->validateOnParse = true;` как написано в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.getelementbyid.php)